# Can I access on the height of a Flutter Widget at the time of creation of the Widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a Widget in which I want to do render a different amount of rows based on the height of the Widget.

```
  Widget handleState(BuildContext context, MyState state) {
    var height = 100;
    return Column(
        children: [
          Text("1. Widget"),
          if (height > 50) Text("2. Widget"),
          if (height > 100) Text("3. Widget"),
          if (height > 150) Text("4. Widget"),
          Text("5. Widget"),
        ]
    );
  }
```

Is there somehow a way to read the height out of the `BuildContext`? Or is there a way to use another Widget to get the allocated height of the Widget as it's drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget for this.

It is similar to the `Builder` widget but except that the framework call the `LayoutBuilder`'s `build` function at layout time and provide the parent widget's constraints.

For example, inside of the `builder` function you can use the `constraints` property to know the parent widget's size.

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        // use parent's constraint here
        return ChildWidget();
    }
)
```